# Add Scrollbar to GridView Populated Programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, gridview

I'm populating a GridView programmatically and I'd like to make it have a scrollbar (rather than expand all the way down the screen). As recommended in other solutions I've found on Google, I've tried adding the following to the CSS:

```
.gridView {
width:600px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
height:500px;
overflow:auto;
}
```

but this had no effect whatsoever. What else can I do?

EDIT: Here is how the above styles were applied in the output:

```
<table class="gridView" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="PanelGridView" style="background-color:White;border-collapse:collapse;">
```

The gridView class is shown as the class for the table, and I've verified that the CSS file is linked to the ASPX by seeing other style changes being applied.

Comment: Could you show ASPX markup - how this style is applied to the grid?

Comment: See my edit. That's the only way I can really show.

Comment: I think this is not going to work like this. You will have to apply this style to a container DIV and place the grid inside of this container

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks! You can post it as an answer if you'd like, so I can select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The style has to be applied to a container (e.g. DIV) and the gridview has to be placed inside of this container.

This way the gridview can be scrolled (if needed) within the DIV.

This is the basic scenario. For more advanced scenarios (e.g. keeping headers fixed while scrolling the content) see http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2011/11/jquery-fixed-header-scrollable-gridview.html